# SQL query to find the date of a buyer's first order from a second seller

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a set of purchase data made by different buyers to different sellers, which looks like this:

```
buyerid || sellerid || orderid || timestamp 

John123 || SellerABC || 123-abc-x1z || 26/07/2019
John123 || SellerABC || 123-abc-i9h || 28/07/2019
John123 || SellerABC || 123-abc-y16 || 28/07/2019
John123 || SellerDEF || 123-def-u13 || 30/07/2019
Bill456 || SellerABC || 456-abc-o34 || 02/08/2019
Bill456 || SellerABC || 456-abc-l3q || 09/08/2019
Bill456 || SellerABC || 456-abc-j5d || 10/08/2019
Bill456 || SellerDEF || 456-def-i61 || 11/08/2019
```

I want to be able to create a view in SQL that retrieves the timestamp of the first time a buyer makes an order from a SECOND seller. If there is no first order from a second seller then there should be a null entry. The resultant view should look like this:

```
buyerid || first_order_second_seller_timestamp 

John123 || 30/07/2019
Bill456 || 11/08/2019
```

I guess there would be some crazy partitions and subqueries to achieve this, but any help would be much appreciated! Currently I can only retrieve the first and last orders using standard SQL functions:

```
SELECT
  "buyerid"
, "min"("timestamp") "first_order_timestamp"
, "max"("timestamp") "last_order_timestamp"
FROM
  default.order_table
GROUP BY "buyerid"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This is a little tricky.  Here is one method using `lag()`:

```
select buyerid, min(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             lag(sellerid) over (partition by buyerid order by timestamp) as prev_sellerid
      from order_table t
     ) t
where prev_sellerid <> sellerid   -- also filters out `NULL` values
group by buyerid;
```

To get `NULL` values, move the filtering to conditional aggregation:

```
select buyerid, min(case when prev_sellerid <> sellerid then timestamp end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(sellerid) over (partition by buyerid order by timestamp) as prev_sellerid
      from order_table t
     ) t
group by buyerid;
```

EDIT:

You could also use two levels of aggregation:

```
select buyerid, min(case when timestamp = 2 then min_timestamp end)
from (select buyerid, sellerid, min(timestamp) as min_timestamp,
             row_number() over (partition by buyerid order by min(timestamp)) as seqnum
      from order_table t
      group by buyerid, sellerid
     ) bs
group by buyerid;
```

This also generalizes to the *nth* sellerid.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2nd max via rank of each buyer's sellerid

```
   Select "buyerid", sellerid, timestamp 
    from  ( 
    SELECT
    "buyerid", sellerid, timestamp
    Rank() over (partition by 
    buyerid, sellerid order by sellerid ) rn
    From table 

   FROM
   default.order_table) where rn=2
```